# jQuery click runs one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-animate

I am working on a jQuery gallery with thumbnails and I have 2 arrows to "scroll" through these thumbnails. I first tried with the click event but my animation only runs one time then.

I have searched the internet and found the `.on( 'click' )` event. I tried this but no result. Even with using `.off( 'click' )` to remove the event after.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
$("#top_slide_button").on( 'click', function () {
    $("#slide_frame").animate( { marginBottom: -50 }, 200);
    $("#top_slide_button").off( 'click' );
});

$("#bottom_slide_button").on( 'click', function () {
    $("#slide_frame").animate( { marginTop: -50 }, 200);
    $("#bottom_slide_button").off( 'click' );
});
```

Comment: sorry... I think the problem is not clear enough...

Comment: What do you need to know to help me?

Comment: can you share the html and css also.. try to create a demo using http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z5GD5/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny http://jsfiddle.net/z5GD5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#top_slide_button").off( 'click' ).on( 'click', function () {
    $("#slide_frame").animate( { marginBottom: -50 }, 200);
});

$("#bottom_slide_button").off( 'click' ).on( 'click', function () {
    $("#slide_frame").animate( { marginTop: -50 }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Tried your code, but got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative values for the animation

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with
>   a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is
>   computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current
>   value of the property.

```
$("#top_slide_button").on('click', function () {
    console.log('click')
    $("#slide_frame").stop(true).animate({
        marginTop: '-=50'
    }, 200);
});

$("#bottom_slide_button").on('click', function () {
    $("#slide_frame").animate({
        marginTop: '+=50'
    }, 200);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z5GD5/)

Comment: This almost solved the problem. The margin now goes further than the frame. So you can scroll as far as you want. That should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the margin is set to 50, moving it down to 50, if you click it again, it stays at 50. you need to increment the margin-top ie adding 50 every time.

ie:

```
$("#top_slide_button").on('click', function () {
    $("#slide_frame").stop(true).animate({
        marginTop: '-=50'
    }, 200);
});

$("#bottom_slide_button").on('click', function () {
    $("#slide_frame").animate({
        marginTop: '+=50'
    }, 200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PbBq2/

Comment: Okay clear. But the same problem now as the answer from Arun P Johny. You can scroll too far. That should not happen.